# date difference function

Tags: asp.net

can any body can teach me how to use the date difference function? using asp.net? please...

Comment: What date difference function, and in what context? Can you explain what you are trying to solve with it?

Answer (score 3):

**Example**

```
var currentDate = DateTime.Now;
var pastDate = new DateTime(2004, 06, 16);
var timeSpan = currentDate - pastDate;
int hoursPassed = timeSpan.TotalHours;
```

You can subtract one date from another to get a timespan which then have [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/02c79d34.aspx) such as:

- [`TimeSpan.TotalHours`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours.aspx)
- [`TimeSpan.TotalMinutes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalminutes.aspx)
- [`TimeSpan.TotalSeconds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalseconds.aspx)
- [`TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds.aspx)